# Create function that calculates an objects state depending on time parameter

Tags: javascript

Say that I have an object that looks like the one:

```
var ticket = {
    state:"Closed", 
    opened:"2014-01-12",
    assiged:"2014-02-03",
    resolved:"2014-04-22",
    propose:"",
    closed:"2014-05-03"
    tmpstateholder:""
    };
```

What I would like is a function that given a string parameter on the form **2014-02-25**

Calculates in what state the ticket were at that date and then returns the object.

```
function calculateState(d,datestring){
    //Calculate in what state the object is in depending on the date string
    //For example in this case when datestring = 2014-02-25 it should return;
    d.tmpstateholder="assiged"
    return d;
}
```

Also note that if the ticket dosn't have to go to all states, for example in the above example the ticket havn't had entered the proposed state.

Note that a ticket object also could look like the below.

```
var ticket = {
    state:"Closed", 
    opened:"2014-01-12",
    assiged:"",
    resolved:"",
    propose:"",
    closed:"2014-05-03",
    tmpstateholder:""
    };
```

Comment: Only using `javascript` ? you can easily do it using `foreach` jquery

Comment: Your logic seems wrong. It's not problem to log the different states, but if there should be only one active state, it should be stored in your data and not calculated on the fly, IMO.

Comment: I want to use javascript in this case because of the amount of checks that needs to be done, and thats why I want to avoid jQuery. =)

Also I know that it seems wrong, but this is how the task looks like, I want to do calculations on history of alot of tickets, and to do that I need to know at exactly which state the ticket were in at a given time =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply enumerate the object, filter out those states whose date is after the time that we are looking for, and take the maximum of the rest:

```
function calculateState(d, datestring) {
    var maxdate = "", state = "";
    for (var s in d)
        if (d[s] <= datestring && d[s] > maxdate) {
            maxdate = d[s];
            state = s;
        }
    return state;
}
```

Now, if your objects do not only contain states but also other properties (that do not hold dates), you either will need to match date-like property values:

```
 …
       if (/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test(d[s]) && d[s] <= …
```

or make a set of all possible states and iterate that instead of the property names of your object:

```
 …
 var allStates = ["opened", "assiged", "resolved", "proposed", "closed"];
 for (var i=0; i<allStates.length; i++) {
     var s = allStates[i];
     …
```

If you have very many possible states, and they can only be ran through in exactly one order, you might also use binary search on that states list.